# How to get current file name from a function inside another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my debug.py:

```
class Debug:
    @classmethod
    def file_name(self):
        import os
        return os.path.basename(__file__)
```

this is my test.py:

```
print Debug.file_name()
```

This will print debug.py while I want to get test.py.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

```
import inspect
import os

class Debug:
    @classmethod
    def file_name(self):
        caller = inspect.stack()[1]
        return os.path.basename(caller[1])
```

Comment: `self` for `classmethod` is always replaced by `cls`, also there is no need in parameter at all, can be `staticmethod` or a plain function instead of a method

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: Tell that to the OP.

Comment: this can be included in answer i guess

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: I think it just belongs in a comment.